# Stuck with Category Theory notation. What is the meaning of 'Corner brackets' ｢ ｣?

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, monoidal-categories

While reading an article, I encountered this expression.
[Expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhSNw.png)

I was wondering if anyone knows what does the corner brackets ｢(upper) and  ｣(down) in this expression do?

Thank you.

Comment: They are defined right there in your image.

Comment: Do they have any special meaning? Or I can just replace them with 'g' and 'f'?

Comment: Some context would be helpful (in addition to correct grammar): Is there any mention of what category $\mathscr{E}$ is? Because $\lceil {C} \rceil D$ is just an object in $\mathscr{E}$ and an object in $\mathscr{D}$ written consecutively…

Comment: @Luke There's only information, that  _C_ , _D_ and _E_ are categories. _C_ × _D_ → _E_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a standard notation, but it is clearly stated that they are functions of the forms
$$
\begin{align*}
\lceil\ \rceil \colon Ob(\mathcal D) \to [\mathcal C,\mathcal E]\\
\lfloor \ \rfloor \colon Ob(\mathcal C) \to [\mathcal D, \mathcal E]
\end{align*}
$$
satisfying the equation
$$
\lceil D\rceil(C) = \lfloor C \rfloor(D)\ .
$$

From the nature of the equation I suppose that there is a bifunctor lurking around, but I cannot be sure with the limited amount of details provided.